# How to read an excel file into r (in the excel, the first row are variable names and the second row variable labels)?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

I have one excel file. The first row contains variable names, and the second row contains variable labels (like the one below).

```
id     age   w
parID  yrs   working?
1      28    0
2      35    1
3      67    0
4      44    1
...
```

When reading this excel file into R, I would like to keep variable names and add labels to corresponding variable names. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: You can have a look at [the function `read.xlsx`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/openxlsx/versions/4.2.5.2/topics/read.xlsx), playing with the parameter `rowNames`.

Comment: AFAIK, R dataframes have strings as "column names" without extra annotation structures (as e.g. in SPSS knows them). Exception: annotated dataframes of package {biobase} https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biobase.html You can try combining the first two rows during import or after, or generate a lookup hash. However, it might be less effort to (re)label the variables for presentational output only.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following pipeline:

1. Import data and labels
2. Handle the labels using either `haven`'s `labelled`-class (preferred) or the `label-attribute`(using the `label`-attribute, here assigned using the `labelled`-package). Alternatively, use the `varlabels`-vector directly below when need be.

**Step 1:**

```r
library(readxl)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

file <- "file.xlsx"

# Get variable names and labels (as named vector)
varnames_varlabels <- 
  read_excel(file, n_max = 1) |>
  pivot_longer(everything()) |>
  deframe()

# Import data
df <-
  read_excel(file, 
             skip = 2,
             col_names = names(varnames_varlabels))
```

**Step 2**

Using `haven`:

```r
library(haven)
library(dplyr)

# Annotate with labels using haven's labelled class
df_labelled <-
  df |>
  mutate(across(everything(),
                ~ labelled(x = ., label = varlabels[cur_column()])
                )
         )
```

```
str(df_labelled)

tibble [4 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ id : dbl+lbl [1:4] 1, 2, 3, 4
   ..@ label: Named chr "parID"
   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "id"
 $ age: dbl+lbl [1:4] 28, 35, 67, 44
   ..@ label: Named chr "years"
   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "age"
 $ w  : dbl+lbl [1:4] 0, 1, 0, 1
   ..@ label: Named chr "working?"
   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "w"
```

Using the `label`-attribute (here annotated using the `labelled` package):

```
library(labelled)

# Annotate using the 'labelled'-package

df_labelled <-
  df |>
  labelled::set_variable_labels(!!!varlabels)
```

```
str(df_labelled)

tibble [4 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
$ id : num [1:4] 1 2 3 4
..- attr(*, "label")= chr "parID"
$ age: num [1:4] 28 35 67 44
..- attr(*, "label")= chr "years"
$ w  : num [1:4] 0 1 0 1
..- attr(*, "label")= chr "working?"
```